# Change encoding multiple file with iconv in bash

Tags: bash, encoding, iconv

I want to change multiple php files encoding with iconv.

I use find and exec option (Reference : http://linux.bigresource.com/Ubuntu-Encoding-Conversion-on-Multiple-Files--4fuXvUwbN.html)

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -print -exec iconv -f euc-kr -t utf-8 {} -o {}.utf8
```

But the error is occured.

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I just want to convert all php files in a once time.
How can i do this with one statement in a bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must put either `\;` or `+` at the end of the `-exec` action.

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -print -exec iconv -f euc-kr -t utf-8 {} -o {}.utf8 \;
```

Comment: You can also use ';' just as you've quoted the '*.php' - only the ";" itself is special to find, the "\" is just to get the shell to leave it alone.  Handy in some scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

after some tests finally found out solution working on my mac

```
for f in *.TXT; do iconv -f CP1250 -t utf-8 $f > $f.txt; done
```